# Escribir Log con Logger - Sobre el mismo archivo

Tags: java

Estoy creando un archivo .log en una ruta especifica, pero tengo un problema, cree una clase static y cada vez que llamo el método de escribirLog se crea una archivo .log nuevo, necesito que el log siempre quede sobre el mismo archivo.

Este es código de prueba:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class Utils {

    public static void escribirLog(String rutaArchivo, String mensaje) {

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
        FileHandler fh;

        try {

            fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo);
            logger.addHandler(fh);

            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);

            logger.info(mensaje);

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        for(int i=1;i<6;i++){
            escribirLog("C:\\rutaLog\\archivo.log", "MensajePrueba"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

En el new FileHandler se crea el archivo, he visto las diferentes formas de crear el new FileHandler(...,true/false); pero sigue creando otros archivos log.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puedo hacer para que siempre se escriba el log sobre el mismo archivo?.

Comment: Estoy confundido, la etiqueta pone log4j pero el código parece utilizar `java.util.logging`. ¿Podrías aclararlo? ¿Cuáles son los imports?

Comment: Sugiero evitar usar JUL y mejor usar un log decente como log4j2 o logback.

Comment: Es cierto @SJuan76, edito para poner los import Java.

Comment: Googlee, pero no logre encontrar una forma crear el archivo log con log4j2 en una ruta especifica.

Comment: "Googlee, pero no logre encontrar una forma crear el archivo log con log4j2 en una ruta especifica" ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/18918225/1065197 ...

Comment: Tu código debería funcionar tal y como lo tienes si agregas al constructor del archivo el append mode al final establecido a `true`, ya que el mismo es `false` por defecto y por eso crea archivos nuevos cada vez: `fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo, true);` de ese modo te permitirá seguir escribiendo sobre el archivo existente. **[Ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698340/5587982)** y la doc de la clase [`FileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase [`FileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) está definida así:

```
public FileHandler(String pattern,
                   boolean append)
            throws IOException,
                   SecurityException
```

Parámetros:

`pattern` - nombre del archivo

`append` - especifica el append mode

El parámetro `append` es el que indica a la clase si se debe crear un archivo nuevo o continuar escribiendo sobre uno ya existente.

Por defecto, su valor es `false`:

> `<handler-name>.append` specifies whether the FileHandler should append
>   onto any existing files (**defaults to false**).

Si quieres que siga escribiendo sobre el mismo archivo, debes establecer ese valor a `true` en el constructor:

```
        fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo, true);
```

De ese modo, evitarás que se cree un nuevo archivo cada vez, y los datos se agregarán al archivo indicado en `rutaArchivo`.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano. Efectivamente con la linea `fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo, true);` funciona, permite escribir sobre el mismo archivo **archivo.log**, sin embargo se siguen generando otros archivos log **archivo.log.1... archivo.log.4** los cuales no requiero, como puedo evitar esto?

Comment: @kradwarrior es posible que necesites cerrar el archivo cuando termines de usarlo, agregando esto al final del bloque `try`: **`fh.close();`** Quizá al invocar repetidamente el método en algunos casos el archivo esté bloqueado por estar abierto y por ese crea uno nuevo.

Comment: Si, efectivamente al final era necesario cerrar el FileHandler con `fh.close();` para que escriba sobre el mismo archivo

Answer (score 0):

Es simple, tienes que modificar una parte del código por esto:

```
fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo, true);
```

Y agregar al final esto:

```
fh.close();
```

Al final debería quedar algo como esto:

```
public static void escribirLog(String rutaArchivo, String mensaje) {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    FileHandler fh;

    try {

        fh = new FileHandler(rutaArchivo, true);
        logger.addHandler(fh);

        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();

        fh.setFormatter(formatter);

        logger.info(mensaje);

        fh.close();

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```